# error in update database

Tags: sql-server-2008

> error ::
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

source  code :

```
cn.Open();
Line 27:         cmd = new SqlCommand("updat product set  status ='" + s + "'", cn);
Line 28:         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 29:         cn.Close();
Line 30:     }
```

Answer (score 5):

1. You realize you spelled `update` wrong?
2. Does `s` possibly have any apostrophe's in it's value?  If so, you need to escape them, i.e., `s.Replace("'", "''")` (or better yet, use parameterized queries)
3. You have a possible SQL Injection vulnerability.
4. Are you sure you intend to update all of the products in the entire table?

Comment: A +1 from me too. Well deserved, especially if the superfluous apostrophes in point #2 were accidental :-)